# What is the derivative for the function $f(x) = \sin^2(x)\sin(x^2)?$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I understand the process of the product rule and chain rule etc. My answer led to $[\sin^2(x)\cos(x^2)(2x)] + \sin(x^2)(2\sin x \cos x).$ According to my solutions manual this is so far correct, however the final answer reads $2\sin(x)[x\cos(x^2)+\cos(x)\sin(x^2)].$ I assume this is some algebraic manipulation with maybe trig identities however I have no idea how. I'd appreciate if someone explained how to arrive at that answer, thank you!

Comment: The previous edit removed lots of MathJax markup... please be careful when making such edits.

Answer (score 3):

We get \begin{align*}
&(\sin^2 x)(\cos(x^2)) (2x)+(\sin (x^2))(2\sin x\cos x)\\
&=2\sin x(x\sin x\cos(x^2)+\sin(x^2)\cos x)
\end{align*} simply by factoring the $2\sin x$ from each term. This is a bit different than the answer you provided, but it is what the answer should be.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $x\sin x\cos(x^2)?$

Comment: @AdrianKeister Yes, typo. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I get
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\left[\sin^2(x)\sin(x^2)\right]&=2\sin(x)\cos(x)\sin\left(x^2\right)+\sin^2(x)\cos\left(x^2\right)(2x)\\
&=2\sin(x)\left[\cos(x)\sin\left(x^2\right)+x\sin(x)\cos\left(x^2\right)\right].
\end{align*}
The term with $\cos\left(x^2\right)$ should still have a $\sin(x)$ multiplying it after factoring, because it was squared originally. Not sure I agree with the book's answer.

Answer (score 1):

No. 
$$
[\sin^2(x)\cos(x^2)(2x)] + \sin(x^2)(2\sin x \cos x)
$$
can be rewritten as
$$
2\sin x \left(x\sin(x) \cos(x^2)+\sin(x^2)\cos(x)\right)
$$